# Using ndk to create and the load a library but having problems with the load

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm currently trying to do the `hello-jni` sample in android studio and I have encountered an issue.

In the static constructor the `System.loadLibrary` doesn't work. This is understandable as I currently haven't added the lib path to `java.library.path`. So I decided to replace it with `System.load` and using the absolute path and now I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1093]: Library 'C:/Users/Public/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/hello-jni/app/src/main/libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so' not found
```

I'm a pretty stumped now and would greatly appreciate a push in the right direction.

Comment: You don't have to do anything with java.library.path. .so files are installed in a specific directory on the device and System.loadLibrary will automatically look inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue I had was to do with the CPU of my emulator.
I ended up using an emulator with an ARM cpu instead of an Intel Atom (x86) and it worked.
Although this solves the immediate problem I am confused about why this is an issue in the first place. I have the .so file in the x86 libs folder. Any reasoning to why it doesn't work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Place your library here:

```
hello-jni/app/libs/armeabi/yourlib.so
```

Add in your activity:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("yourlib");
}
```

Add in your build.gradle:

```
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that originally but to no avail I'm afraid. I got the same error but with "Couldn't load hello-jni: findLibrary returned null"

Comment: Are you sure that you test device is on ARM architecture?

Comment: I'm using an emulator with the Intelx86 cpu which I figured would be fine because I've used productFlavors to create x86, armeabi-v7a and mips build variants. I changed the absolute path in the System.load to match this but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure libs folder exists and you have .so files present in them. If your .so files exist in the jni/libs folder then you need to inform the build system to look for the .so files there. Add the following to your build.gradle

```
sourceSets.main
            {
                jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            }
```

Do not use absolute path in your static loadlibrary method

Check this video for how to create NDK apps with Android studio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFtxo7rr2HQ&list=UUkbLy9aj5IBXfS6WqLy5Qmw

Comment: Thanks for the response but I've tried that. I did just find out what was up though. It seems that this is due to running it on an emulator with the intel atom (x86) chip. I swapped to an arm based emulator and it works... I'm not sure why this is the case as I have the x86 with the .so in

Comment: This is weird. Add the keyword "fat" at the end of your product flavors module and build it again to generate a fat binary and try it with an Intel emulator.